# Where do Orpheus bpl files get generated?

Tags: delphi, turbopower

I am trying to add the latest incarnation of Orpheus 4.08 to Delphi XE2 and Delphi XE3. Other than the usual warnings, the packages compile without errors and the compiler signals success. However, I cannot find the *.bpl files. They are not in the bin directory with the other VCL files, and a search of my (indexed) drive does not locate them anywhere else. Where should I be looking, or have they not been created?

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded the latest code from the SVN repo: https://tporpheus.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/tporpheus/trunk. I then built all projects in the package group. The output .bpl files landed here:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl   (for XE2)
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\10.0\Bpl  (for XE3)
```

Where the files will land on your machine depends on your IDE settings. The setting that counts is the Package output directory found under Tools | Options | Environment Options | Delphi Options | Library. The default value is `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Bpl` which, at least on my machine, expands to the directories shown above.

Comment: Thanks, David. SourceForge does not appear to allow FTP downloads. The link you gave me above leads to a list of many files but now link to download. May I ask how you got all of the files quickly ? It's been quite a while since I've been on SourceForge and I need some reminders. TIA !

Comment: You need a subversion client. You should be able to check it out from the Delphi IDE directly if you don't have a subversion client to hand.

Comment: Read the sourceforge instructions here: http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=71004&source=navbar You'll find that you don't need to fix anything when you check out the head. The source has been updated for XE2 and XE3. Rule 1 of open source today is to use the repo rather than the pre-packaged downloads. Pre-packages downloads are invariably out of date.

Comment: Got it now. I downloaded a subversion client from SlikSVN. I now have Build 270. Thanks, David !

Comment: Good. Does this answer the question then?